# SSRS Improving the Speed of String Counts

Tags: performance, reporting-services, sum, contains

I've created an SSRS report that takes a single column of strings from a SQL query and counts the number of times specific values occur within the strings. For clarity's sake, the data frame I'm starting with looks like this:

| String |
| --- |
| Fish [a] [b] |
| Car [a] |
| Truck [b] |
| Airplaine [a] [c] |
| Second [a] [b] [c] |

Using the following three expressions:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!String.Value.Contains("[a]")="True",1,0))
=SUM(IIf(Fields!String.Value.Contains("[b]")="True",1,0))
=SUM(IIf(Fields!String.Value.Contains("[c]")="True",1,0))
```

I get the following output table:

| Subtype | Number of Subtype in Strings |
| --- | --- |
| a | 4 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 2 |

The report works, but my actual report contains 14 groups that I am sorting into using 14 expressions, so the processing time is exceedingly long (10 minutes+). Is there another way of accomplishing this that takes less processing power?

Comment: How many records is the report processing? It might be faster to do it in your dataset query, so if you could provide a more realistic sample of data and approx number of records in your real data we'd have something to work with.

Comment: The report is processing 300,000 records. I have no doubt it would be faster to do the processing in my base query. My only concern is that there is no grouping variable in the dataset. I'm a novice in SQL so I'm unaware of how to count within strings and save to newly created variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have a specific list of strings that you are looking for, if you do, let me know and I'll update the answer. Also let me know if this list of strings is being set from a report parameter or not as that will change the answer.

As I've not got any of your real data to test with so I've just used some data from the Demo database "Adventure Works 2019", although note that this will work for SQL Server 2016 or later.

I've taken the `JobTitle` column from the `Employee` table as my sample data, here you can see the kind of things if contains.

```
SELECT LoginID, JobTitle FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[HumanResources].[Employee]
```

[image]

I'm only showing the LoginID here so you can see that some jobtitles are repeated.

Now, to get a count of every word, we can use `string_split()` to split the text into words, then all we do is group by the words returned and do a simple `count(*)` across the results.

```
SELECT a.Value, COUNT(*) as StringCount
    FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[HumanResources].[Employee]
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(JobTitle, ' ') a
    GROUP BY a.Value
```

Here's the (shortened) results..

[image]

If we apply the same method to your sample data then the code looks like this

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(myString varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Fish [a] [b]'),
('Car [a]'),
('Truck [b]'),
('Airplaine [a] [c]'),
('Second [a] [b] [c]')

SELECT a.Value, COUNT(*) as StringCount
    FROM @t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(myString, ' ') a
    WHERE a.Value in ('[a]', '[b]', '[c]')
    GROUP BY a.Value
```

Note that I've added a where clause to filter down to the 3 strings you want to find.

We get the following results

[image]

Comment: To answer your questions, no - these are not making use of parameters. Another thing is that in my strings there are no spaces between brackets. That was an error with my initial example. The brackets are right beside one anohter, like [a][b][c].

This is a very elegant solution, but when I try to implement it I'm running into a small snag. My organization uses IBMi, and when I try to run your query I get the following error:

42000 -104 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token APPLY was not valid. Valid tokens: JOIN.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Apologies, I had assumed MS SQL Sever was being used. DB2 and i Series are not things I'm very familiar with (not touched an IBM database for 25 years!). I'm sure somebody more knowledgeable than me would know how to convert this though... Pity as I faked 300K rows and even on my 8 year old desktop top that acts as a test server, it only took about 15 seconds. Good luck!